# Generators and Relations and Homomorphisms

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism, group-presentation

Let's say we have a homomorphism $\phi: G \rightarrow H$ where $G$ and $H$ group. Say $G$ is generated by some generators and relations, for an example $$G = \langle r,s \mid r^{4}=1 , r^2=s^2, rsr=s\rangle.$$ Now, since $\phi$ is a homomorphism then those generators and relations are satisfied by $\phi(r)$ and $\phi(s)$.

Now if we show that $\phi(r) \ne \phi(s), |\phi(r)|=|\phi(s)|= 4 $  is it sufficient to show that the group generated by $\phi(r)$ and $\phi(s)$ is isomorphic to $G$?

Is this true in general? What I mean is if images of each generator have the same order as the generators and images of each generator are different group elements in the image, does it say the group generated by the images of generators is a subgroup of $H$?

Thanks!

Comment: The group generated by the images of the generators is equal to the image of the morphism, which is *always* a subgroup of the codomain. Are you sure your last question is what you meant to ask?

Comment: In general no. Take the group generated by $r$ and $s$ subject to $r^4=s^4=1$, $rs=sr$. This is the group $C_4\times C_4$. But you can map it to a cyclic group of order $4$ generated by $x$ by sending $r$ to $x$ and $s$ to $x^3$. Images are different, of the same orders as the generators, but your map is not one-to-one, so the image is not isomorphic to $G$.

Comment: Thank you for both answers.